# Create an array with values from other array with push without creating a bidimensional array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array that has the values from 1 to 13, four times. This final array should have 52 positions and be something like this:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

I already created the array filled with numbers from 1 to 13

`let suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)`

And want to push four times the values on this "suit" array to a final array called "deck".

To do this I've tried the following code:

```
let suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)
let suitsNumber = 4
let deck = []

for(let i = 0; i < suitsNumber; i++ ) {
   deck.push(suit)
}
```

The problem is that the resulting array "deck" is a bidimensional array with length four and in each position is the array suit:

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]

Can someone tell why is not working as I expected?

Comment: `deck.push(...suit)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `deck.push(...suit)` instead of `deck.push(suit)`. This will push the individual numbers to the `deck` array instead of pushing the entirety of `suit` array to an index of the `deck` array.

```js
let suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)
let suitsNumber = 4
let deck = []

for (let i = 0; i < suitsNumber; i++) {
  deck.push(...suit)
}

console.log(deck)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `concat` with spread syntax `...` one the main array that contains other 4 sub-arrays.

```js
const result = [].concat(...Array(4).fill(Array.from(Array(13), (_, i) => i + 1)))
console.log(result)
```

Or you can use `flat()` method on the array containing other 4 sub-arrays.

```js
const result = Array(4).fill(Array.from(Array(13), (_, i) => i + 1)).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too

```
const suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)
const deck = Array.from(new Array(suit.length * 4), (_, index) => suit[index % 13])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an 2d array, and flatten it with [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)
const suitsNumber = 4
const deck = Array.from(new Array(suitsNumber), () => suit).flat()

console.log(deck)
```

Or use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create the array:

```js
const suit = Array.from(new Array(13), (x, index) => index + 1)
const suitsNumber = 4
const deck = new Array(suitsNumber).fill(null).flatMap(() => suit)

console.log(deck)
```